# "That is *how* I am called"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I used to think it's incorrect to say "*how* something is called", that it's a common mistake of non-native speakers, and that we must use "what" instead. But I just came across the following sentence in a book:

> That is **how** I am called, my Lord: Hayt.

(from Dune Messiah, chapter 6)

It must be correct, right? But why?

Comment: Can you edit to give the source of your quotation? This is important as, to my ears, it sounds archaic.

Comment: @mdewey edited!

Comment: "How" someone is called is archaic English. Now we say 'what'. The 'Dune' books by Frank Herbert are 'fantasy novels'. Often the characters of these talk in ways that are meant to be like the Earth in 'ancient' or 'mediaeval' times, but not too much (e.g. like in Chaucer) as then most of the readers would struggle.

Comment: Why do you think it must be right?  Authors aren't perfect.